# Can't assign images from an array into a collection view

Tags: arrays, image, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to assign image assets from an array into a collection view.  There is one line I'm struggling with.  Does anyone have a suggestion on what I am doing wrong?  The problem is with the cell item.  My code is:

```
         override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell
        println("just seeing when this prints")
        println(self.matchedSelfie)

        cell.match.image = self.matchedSelfie

            return cell
```

The problem is with the cell.match.image = self.matchedSelfie

Comment: What is the problem? If the cell is nil, you should create a new CollectionViewCell instance. Is there an image in the self.matchedSelfie?

Comment: There are 9 images stored in the matchedSelfie array. I don't know how to assign those as the match items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the correct image using:

```
cell.match.image = self.matchedSelfie[indexPath.row]
```

Assuming that the order of the images in the array are the same as the order of the cells.

Comment: Match keeps coming back as nil. I added the line '
     
if cell.match != nil { cell.match.image = self.matchedSelfie[indexPath.row] return cell } else { println("error") return cell'   That only prints the error to the console.

Comment: But you do have a cell object? Because you only dequeue one. You do not instantiate a new cell if it can not be dequeued. And if you do create a new cell instance, do you load it from a .xib or storyboard? of so, then have you linked the image to the .match property?

Comment: ![screen shot of the story board] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcdrbnk13nms5z3/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-12%20at%208.18.41%20AM.png?dl=0)

Comment: My cell code is pretty basic:
    `import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   
    @IBOutlet var match: UIImageView!
    
    
}`